# Use analytic function result in where clouse

Tags: sql, oracle, lag

I got this statement:

```
select ar.*,
LAG(DEST_TIME, 1) OVER (order by FEP_ID) HIT 
from dsyy.archiv ar;
```

It works pretty fine.
now I want to do something like that:

```
select ar.*,
    LAG(DEST_TIME, 1) OVER (order by FEP_ID) HIT 
    from dsyy.archiv ar 
    where ARR_TIME < HIT;
```

Unfortunality that is not allowed...
Could you tell me how I can deal with the column `HIT` inside the `where-clouse`?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use a subquery:

```
select ar.*
from (select ar.*,
             LAG(DEST_TIME, 1) OVER (order by FEP_ID) HIT 
      from dsyy.archiv ar 
     ) ar
where ARR_TIME < HIT;
```